# NSMutableSet vs NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

What's the difference?

In my context, I need to be able to dynamically add to and remove objects. The user clicks on rows of a table that check on and off and thus add or remove the referenced object from the list.

A wild guess is that array has indexed items while set has no indexes?

Comment: Make sure to upvote the answers that helped you, rather than leave a comment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An `NSSet`/`NSMutableSet` doesn't keep items in any particular order. An `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` does store the items in a particular order. If you're building a table view, you should definitely use an array as your data source of choice.

Comment: Also, if the order is irrelevant and you frequently ask whether a particular item belongs to the group or not, it is much more efficient to use `NSSet` rather than `NSArray`.

Answer (score 23):

Also, NSMutableSet makes sure that all objects are unique.

NSMutableArray goes well with UITableView since elements have index, so you can return [array count] to get number of table rows, or [array objectAtIndex:rowNumber] to easily associate element with row.

Comment: This is something I didn't realize

Answer (score 3):

Also, according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_0), testing for object membership is faster with NSSets.

> You can use sets as an alternative to arrays when the order of
>   elements isn’t important and performance in testing whether an object
>   is contained in the set is a consideration—while arrays are ordered,
>   testing for membership is slower than with sets.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 3 main differences. 1) Sets are unordered 2)Don't have an index & 3)Cannot have duplicate values where Arrays are ordered, indexed & can store duplicate values.